# Atmospheric entry of asteroid mining products

Tags: landing, asteroid, mining, entry-descent-landing

This is a more general question than [How to get processed asteroid metals back to Earth in a safe manner](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/14157/how-to-get-processed-asteroid-metals-back-to-earth-in-a-safe-manner)

That question was actually a quick check to see if a particular idea was plausible.  Instead, I would like to know what peer reviewed ideas exist for safely landing large masses on the Earth?

Comment: "safely" is relative;   **cost** is overwhelming.